# Long press in react using Event-deligation

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling, mouseevent

How to identify a long press event on react without using javascript setTimeout function only by using event deligation

Comment: Probably react has got nothing to do with what you trying to achieve. I don't believe you can do it in without using `setTimeout` at all in the browser using JavaScript, because there is no such thing as `longpress` event. You should use mouse and touch events and implement it yourself.

Comment: we can also use Date() function and compare mousedown and mouse up